# How to effectively patch code running on multiple hosts?

Tags: php, codeigniter, deployment, release-management

A product is a CMS under constant development and new features patches are always being rolled out. The product is hosted on multiple servers for some of which I just have FTP credentials and access to db and for others I have full root access. Now, as soon as a new feature is released after testing and all I have to manually ftp files and run SQL queries on all servers. This is very time consuming, error prone and inefficient. How can I make it more robust, fool proof or automate parts of it? The CMS is based on PHP, MySQL, JS, HTML and CSS. The admin part is common for all. Skins and some custom modules are developed for different clients and the only part we update is admin.

**Update**

For managing code we use GIT, SQL is not part of this GIT structure and I will be talking to product manager/owners to have it under version control.

Comment: Do you use a versioning system of any kind? (CVS, SVN, git)?

Comment: I've been dealing with a similar topic recently and came across this article: http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/from-ftp-to-git-a-deployment-story/. It gives some interesting ideas about the differences between deploymen and file trasnfer. Also make sure to check out Git Hooks (http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/tools-and-tips/quick-tip-automation-with-git-hooks/), which may be a quite interesting approach in your case.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the big questions of unpackaged code.

Personally, I have a PHAR, which when executed, extracts code to the specific folder and executes needed queries.

Comment: I would have favored a native package for a system. For one of the product I worked we used to roll out RPM packages. Minor releases every Friday. Just install the package and it updates everything. But in current situation some hosts are rackspace cloudsites, some are not owned by us, some are simple shared hosting solutions.

Comment: It's 2012. I don't see what the problem w/ having SFTP as a requirement is. I'd bet every host that you currently log into via FTP would prefer you use SFTP isntead.

Answer (score 1):

I've run web deployments across dozens of servers handling hundreds of millions of visitors/month.

SQL change management is always going to be a beast. You're only hope is either rolling your own in house (what I did) or using something like [EMS DB Comparer](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/dbcomparer).

To handle the file syncing, you're going to need a number of tools, all expertly crafted to work together, including:

1. Source code version control (bzr, svn, etc.), that is properly branched (stable branch, dev branch, testing branch are required),
2. A Continuous Integration server,
3. SFTP support on every server,
4. Hopefully unit and integrative tests to determine build quality,
5. Rsync on every server,
6. Build scripts (I do these in Phing),
7. Deployment scripts (in Phing as well),
8. Know how.

The general process takes approximately 20 hours to research thoroughly and about 40 hours to set up. When I drew up my documentation, there were over 40 distinct steps involved.  Creating the SQL change management utility took another 20-30 hours.  Add in another 10 hours of testing, and you're looking at a 100-120 hour project, but one which will save you considerably in botched deployments in the future as well as reduce deployment time to the time it takes to click a button.

That's why I do consultations on setting up this entire process, and it usually takes ~5 hours to set up on a client's network.

Comment: From a business perspective this all looks very expensive. We do not have SFTP for every server, if we had that I would have written a script to push code to all servers, run post deployment steps etc.

Comment: @Kumar Actually, every single thing on that list except a SQL change management app (which you *can* make in-house) is open sourced and free.  The tools don't cost the money, it's the knowledge, missteps, and getting everything just right that does.

Comment: its not the app but man hours that will go into setting this up. The product is from a very small enterprise and is very very localised product. I am actually looking at how WordPress updates work. Regardless of current product, I will be exploring whatever you have mentioned, just for science :-)